# Error cannot open tty-output Linux

Tags: boot, syslog

I have installed one paravirtualized image, Debian 8, in `XenServer`, and I'm adding a script to create a template that come. Added in the startup script with the command `systemctl enable script`. `Scritp` I use in the dialog that is already installed.

When I come to convert the template and create a new VM, the `syslog` log me the following error appears as if the script had starting at the wrong time of boot:

```
initial-conf[407]: Error opening terminal: unknown.
initial-conf[407]: cannot open tty-output
initial-conf[407]: Error opening terminal: unknown.
```

Comment: This usually happens because the environment variable TERM is missing. Try add into your .service file just below [Service] section the variable: Environment=TERM="linux".

Answer (score 1):

i had something like your issue.
Hapened when i switch to another user terminal with su for run the same script:

```
$ su another-user
```

in my case, i had to open a new terminal for run my script

the same issue hapen with putty

so i opened other terminal for a new session for the another user